# Generalize the construction of a Greek-Roman Matrix - Python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, traversal

I wrote a python program that has as input a matrix, in which, each element appears in each row and column once. Elements are only positive integers.

e.g.

```
0,2,3,1
3,1,0,2
1,3,2,0
2,0,1,3
```

Then i find all possible traversals. They are defined as such:

- choose an element from the first column
- move on to the next column and
- choose the element that is not in the same line from previous elements in traversal and the element has not the same value with previous elements in traversal.

e.g.

```
0,*,*,*
*,*,*,2
*,3,*,*
*,*,1,*
```

I have constructed the code that finds the traversals for matrices 4x4, but i have trouble generalizing it for NxN matrices. My code follows below. Not looking for a solution, any tip would be helpful.

```
import sys       # Import to input arguments from cmd.
import pprint    # Import for a cool print of the graph
import itertools # Import to find all crossings' combinations

# Input of arguments
input_filename = sys.argv[1]

# Create an empty graph
g = {} 
# Initialize variable for the list count
i = 0 

# Opens the file to make the transfer into a matrix
with open(input_filename) as graph_input:
    for line in graph_input:
        # Split line into four elements.
        g[i] = [int(x) for x in line.split(',')]
        i += 1

# Initialize variable
var = 0
# Lists for the crossings, plus rows and cols of to use for archiving purposes
f = {}
r = {}
c = {}
l = 0

# Finds the all the crossings
if len(g) == 4:
    for x in range (len(g)): 
        for y in range (len(g)):
            # When we are in the first column
            if y == 0:
                # Creates the maximum number of lists that don't include the first line
                max_num = len(g) -1
                for z in range (max_num):
                    f[l] = [g[x][y]]
                    r[l] = [x]
                    c[l] = [y]
                    l += 1
            # When on other columns
            if y != 0:
                for z in range(len(g)):
                    # Initializes a crossing archive
                    used = [-1]
                    for item in f:
                        # Checks if the element should go in that crossing
                        if f[item][0] == g[x][0]:
                            if g[z][y] not in f[item] and z not in r[item] and y not in c[item] and g[z][y] not in used:
                                # Appends the element and the archive  
                                f[item].append(g[z][y])
                                used.append(g[z][y])
                                r[item].append(z)
                                c[item].append(y)

# Removes unused lists 
for x in range (len(f)):
    if len(f[x]) != len(g):
        f.pop(x)

#Transfers the value from a dictionary to a list
f_final = f.values()

# Finds all the combinations from the existing crossings
list_comb = list(itertools.combinations(f_final, i))

# Initialize variables
x = 0
w = len(list_comb)
v = len(list_comb[0][0])

# Excludes from the combinations all invalid crossings
while x < w:
    # Initialize y
    y = 1
    while y < v:
        # Initialize z
        z = 0
        while z < v:
            # Check if the crossings have the same element in the same position
            if list_comb[x][y][z] == list_comb[x][y-1][z]:
                # Removes the combination from the pool
                list_comb.pop(x)
                # Adjust loop variables
                x -= 1
                w -= 1
                y = v
                z = v
            z += 1
        y += 1
    x += 1  

# Inputs the first valid solution as the one to create the orthogonal latin square
final_list = list_comb[0]

# Initializes the orthogonal latin square matrix
orthogonal = [[v for x in range(v)] for y in range(v)]

# Parses through the latin square and the chosen solution
# and creates the orthogonal latin square
for x in range (v):
    for y in range (v):
        for z in range (v):
            if final_list[x][y] == g[z][y]:
                orthogonal[z][y] = int(final_list[x][0])
                break

# Initializes the orthogonal latin square matrix
gr_la = [[v for x in range(v)] for y in range(v)]

# Creates the greek-latin square
for x in range (v):
    for y in range (v):
        coords = tuple([g[x][y],orthogonal[x][y]])
        gr_la[x][y] = coords

pprint.pprint(gr_la)
```

Valid traversals for the 4x4 matrix above are:

```
[[0123],[0312],[3210],[3021],[1203],[1032],[2130],[2301]]
```

Comment: *Tip*: try thinking of this recursively. You make one choice by: taking an element from the first column, removing that column and that row, removing the remaining elements with the chosen value (e.g. replace them with `None`), and you are left with a smaller matrix in which you have to do the same thing. Then you call the function you are defining recursively. The base case is either the 1x1 matrix or even the 0x0 matrix, whichever you find more natural.

Comment: By the way, the matrix you wrote down has no valid traversals. Not sure how to read the proposed list of "valid traversals", but they definitely don't apply to the one you gave.